# Video.js doesn't try other available sources on failure

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I don't understand why HTML5 fallback works properly but Video.js doesn't.

I have made two simple examples to illustrate that I'm trying to explain. If one source fails, the player should switch to the next available source.

**Base Layout**

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
         height="300"
         width="600"
         controls autoplay>
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans_FAILS.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">   
</video>
```

Example 1 - **HTML5**

http://output.jsbin.com/xadihumoka/3

It follows perfectly the W3C HTML5 spec of "The resource selection algorithm for a media element".

Example 2 - **Video.js**

http://output.jsbin.com/koracuboyo/1

Get errored and doesn't recover from error state.

I cannot find any documentation about this problem on video.js github page or the resource selection algorithm for a media element implemented by video.js. I know they use a tech order for determine the source to play, but they only consider **1 working¿?** source per tech.

I'm asking here instead of in the video.js issue tracking system(github) because they close by default the non-core issues.

Comment: Why do you need two video source with the same format? Even though the W3C specs are supporting it, in what use case is it really useful?

Comment: When you have the same resource in two or more CDN's. The network is not as reliable as we think.
Sometimes we have to duplicate instances/resources/apps/services to ensure service availability.

Comment: Videojs is working as expected here. You explicitly state the first video is an mp4 so it will load via HTML5. 

Since the URL returns a 404 error you get the correct error message: "The video could not be loaded, **either because the server or network failed** or because the format is not supported."

Comment: 5 year later I have the same problem... I'm using cloudfront but is too expensive so I want to try another one, but I don't know if the new one is reliable. then, I want to add the new CDN as the primarly source and cloudfront as a backup, someone had solved this?

Comment: Have you tried to isolate your problem? Make the most simple example and test with a plain video tag and with video.js setup. 
Maybe this will be fixed after 5 years :)